# Summarize data frame based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, summarization

I have this kind of dataset (ID, V1, V2 are the 3 variables of my data frame):

```
ID V1 V2 
1  A  10
1  B  5
1  D  1
2  C  9
2  E  8
```

I would like a new data frame with, for each ID, the line that has the value max in V2. For the example, the result would be:

```
ID V1 V2 
1  A  10
2  C  9
```

Comment: What about cases where there are ties for "max"?

Comment: In my case it is impossible

Comment: If you're interested in `data.table` solution, then: `dt[dt[, .I[which.max(V2)], by=ID]$V1]`

Comment: @Arun, much less clumsy...

Comment: @Arun +1, but I'd go with the `.SD` solution by default and use the `.I` one iff speed necessitates so (because the `.SD` one is simpler and because it should be fixed to be as fast at some point in the future); `dt[, .SD[which.max(V2)], by = ID]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of clumsy code, but it works....

```
> mydf[with(mydf, ave(V2, ID, FUN = function(x) x == max(x))) == 1, ]
  ID V1 V2
1  1  A 10
4  2  C  9
```

Less clumsy:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        by(mydf, mydf$ID, 
           FUN = function(x) x[which.max(x$V2), ]))
#   ID V1 V2
# 1  1  A 10
# 2  2  C  9
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ddply` from plyr package (assume data is sample)

```
    library(plyr)
    ddply(sample,.(ID),summarize,V1=V1[which.max(V2)],V2=max(V2))

  ID V1 V2
1  1  A 10
2  2  C  9
```